# java: press next and previouse button to change pic

Tags: java

[the code is not working 100% correct.
when i click next it will change picture(it is working). but when i press previouse button to go to previouse picture it will not show previouse picture. it will show next pic then current pic again then will show prevoiuse picture.
help me please
][1]

```
//next picture
int count=0;
String[] imagenames={"black.png","blue.png","gray.png","green.png","orange.png","purple.png","red.png","yellow.png"};
private void btnnextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    ImageIcon[] imagelist= new ImageIcon[8];
    for(int i = 0; i < imagelist.length;i++){
        imagelist[i]= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/"+ imagenames[i]));
        if(count<0) count = 0;
        if(count>=0 && count < imagenames.length){
            jLabel1.setIcon(imagelist[count]);
            count++;
        }
    }
```

}

```
//previous picture
//i use the same array imagenames
private void btnbackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    ImageIcon[] imagelist= new ImageIcon[8];
    for(int i = 0; i < imagelist.length;i++){
    imagelist[i]= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/"+ imagenames[i]));
    }
    if(count >= imagenames.length)count= imagenames.length-2;

    if(count>=0&& count < imagenames.length){
        jLabel1.setIcon(imagelist[count]);
        count--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to understand your code, the code repetition doesn't really help. You initialize the ImageIcon array every time a button is clicked, that is a waste as well. You can do that outside the methods, like this:

```
class MyComponent {
    ImageIcon[] imagelist = new ImageIcon[8];
    {
        imagenames[] = { //... };
        for (int i = 0; i < imagelist.length; i++) {
            imagelist[i] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/"+ imagenames[i]));
        }
    } // now you can reuse the Icons every time

    int currentImageIndex = 0; // better name, no?
    private void btnnextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        currentImageIndex = Math.max(currentImageIndex+1, imagelist.length-1);
        updateIcon(); // reuse in both button handler methods
    }
    private void btnbackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        currentImageIndex = Math.min(currentImageIndex-1, 0);
        updateIcon();
    }
    private void updateIcon() {
        jLabel1.setIcon(imagelist[currentImageIndex]);
    }
}
```

I don't even know if that fixes your problem; I haven't found the reason of your issue because the code is so hard to read I gave up on finding it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this can be done in a simpler way like so:

For the "Next Picture" button:

```
private void btnnextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // check if we are out of the upper limit
    if (count >= imagenames.length-1) {
        count = imagenames.length-2;
    }

    // check if we are out of the lower limit
    if (count < 0) {
        count = 0;
    }

    // switch to next image
    jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/"+ imagenames[++count])));
}
```

For the "Previous Picture" button:

```
private void btnbackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // check if we are out of the upper limit
    if (count > imagenames.length-1) {
        count = imagenames.length-1;
    }

    // check if we are out of the lower limit
    if (count =< 0) {
        count = 1;
    }

    // switch to prev image
    jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/"+ imagenames[--count])));
}
```